# Looking for an example of a measurable space where $\|\delta_a-\delta_b\|\not=2$ for pointmass measures

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

Given a measurable space $(X,M)$ let $\delta_a$ and $\delta_b$ be the pointmass measures at points $a$ and $b$ in $X$ (suppose $X$ has at least two points to avoid trivialities).  It easy to see that $\|\delta_a+\delta_b\|=2$.  Out of curiosity, I'm trying to find an example of a measurable space where $\|\delta_a-\delta_b\|\not=2$.

Comment: Which norm $\|\cdot\|$ do you consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a $\sigma$-algebra where $a$ and $b$ do not live in distinct elements of a partition. For instance let $X=\{a,b,c\}$, and 
$$
M=\{\varnothing, X, \{a,b\}, \{c\}\,\}.
$$
This is a $\sigma$-algebra (contains complements, unions, intersections). And, for any $Y\in M$, you have $\delta_a(Y)=\delta_b(Y)$. So $\delta_a-\delta_b=0$.